# Calabash-android: зачем подписывать APK и что делать, если подписать не получается

Tags: android

Начала изучать тему автотестов на андроиде, выбрала связку calabash+cucumber.

Следую [этой статье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/219655/). Дошла по п.4:

> "Необходимо переподписать приложение"

Дальше начинаются пляски с бубнами, чтобы это сделать. Путем долгих проб и ошибок, приложение все же удалось подписать, выполнив следующие шаги:

1. Из директории с keytool открываем окно команд, делаем следующее:

   ```
   keytool -genkey -v -keystore \path_to_project\debug.keystore -alias debugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -dname "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US"
   ```

   keystore создан
2. `cd \path_to_project\`
3. `calabash-android setup`
4. Далее последовательно отвечаем на вопросы, я вводила те же значения, что и в п.1
5. Все сохранилось в `.calabash_settings` в текущей папке
6. `calabash-android resign my.apk`
7. `adb install -r my.apk`

И тут ошибка -

> INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES

Ошибку не удается исправить. Как быть? Насколько верны шаги и где я могла допустить неточность, что мне выдается такая ошибка? Есть альтернативные методы, как надо сделать правильно?

P.S. К сожалению, выполнив шаги точно по шаблону из статьи, я наблюдаю ошибки еще с момента переподписания APK (не находит keystore, test server), поэтому я выбрала такой изощренный способ подписи.

P.S.S. Я не программист, SDK скачано, но там нет ни одного проекта. Учусь на примере того самого cleanmaster, как в статье. Так-то я читала, что подпись производится автоматически, когда разрабатываешь свое приложение в Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

Не зачем плясать с бубном вокруг консоли. В Android Studio есть все необходимое для того, что бы создать хранилище, ключ и подписать приложение.

[image: Android studio]